# Fixed array shape/dimensions in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

When typing numpy arrays in cython, is it possible to specify a fixed shape for some dimensions?

Something like

```
cdef something(np.ndarray[dtype=np.float64_t, ndim=2, shape="*, 5"] arg):
    ...
```

which would only allow arrays to be passed if they had 5 columns.

Comment: You could just do `if arg.shape[1] != 5: raise TypeError("2nd dimension of arg must have length 5")`? I don't think there's any advantage to having it specified in the type, apart from saving typing.

Comment: You're correct, but when my functions have say 5 arguments (all with fixed shape) and 5-10 lines of real code, that means that ~50% of my lines code are just those shape tests. And when you have a collection of functions, it definitely makes the code harder to read